# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, importerror

I keep getting this error in VS Code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\User Name\Documents\Productivity\Coding\Python\Udemy\Projects from course\MilestoneP2\app.py", line 1, in <module>
          import MilestoneP2.utils.Operations_db as Db
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MilestoneP2'
```

I have recently shifted from Pycharm to VS Code and I am trying to open some of those projects from pycharm in VS Code but there is the above error haunting me.

PS: I have my Python Interpreter in a different directory and not in the workspace folder. It's in `D:\Python\venv` Drive

Here is my code:

```
import MilestoneP2.utils.Operations_db as Db
```

Here is the file hierarchy.

[image]

Anyone Help?

Thank you

Comment: have you activated the virtual enviroment?

Comment: How do you do that? I am new to VS Code..

Comment: then just pip install the module you need in the console

Answer (score 0):

If you run the script within VSCode there is a Python version button on bottom-left.

[image: interpreter]

When you click on it you can specify your Python or virtual environment path. It will also try to find them automatically from directories. Then you can run your scripts with the spesified environments.

[image: You can specify your Python or virtual environment path]

Comment: Yeah, there are two and I tried it in both, and both returns the same error.

Comment: Did you activate and installed the MilestoneP2 on that environment? Because if your pip installation path is not the same with the VSCode it would give the error. If you use a custom module that you have written yourself. Then you need __init__.py file in the MilestoneP2 directory.

Comment: I think the first part of your answer is causing problems.I'll look into it and get back to you and as for Init.py I have it in the packages folder